# ajax will not hit success

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to get data from my webapi server. Debugging shows

```
GET http://localhost:62578/api/DB [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
```

but I dont hit success, instead I hit error and no data is passed in to the error function?

```
var records;
var loadedData = new Array();

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',  
    accept: "application/json",
    url: 'http://localhost:62578/api/DB',
    //data: { a:'a' },
   // contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
    //I never get here.
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {//key is the row number, val is the  object data below
                $.each(val, function (key2, val2) {//key2 is the array element name, val2 is the data. 
                    if (key == 0) loadedData.push(key2);  //we only need one row of collumns
                });
                records = key;
                init(loadedData);   
                });
            },
             error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            //both return undefined.
        }
        });
```

webapi server log.

jttp = http FYI ( stupid Stack OverFlow )

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=jttp://localhost:62578/api/DB, Message='jttp://localhost:62578/api/DB'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='DB', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='MvcApplication1.Controllers.DBController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='MvcApplication1.Controllers.DBController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'GetAllProducts()'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Action returned 'MvcApplication1.Models.DataBase[]'', Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=DBController.ExecuteAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=200 (OK), Method=GET, Url=jttp://localhost:62578/api/DB, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=DBController.Dispose
```

Comment: are you using localhost or it just an example `localhost:62578/api/DB`? make sure to add `http://`

Comment: jqXHR.status is 0,   
jqXHR.responseText is undefined,   
exception is undefined

Comment: Stackoverflow kept nagging me about putting http in my post, it would not let me continue with http"\\ in there.

Comment: there you go, http is now there :)

Comment: thx friend! Also I'm see different output now, not sure I didnt anything to change this. though still not helpful. ----jqXHR.status is 0,   
jqXHR.responseText is "",   
exception is "error"

Comment: What is running on the server side? Does it log errors?

Comment: oh because I'm canceling the event with alerts.

Comment: I'll have to look in to that BNL I dont know hoe to check the logs.

Comment: I figured out how ot get my log but I can not answer my own question :( So I will add it to my first post.

Comment: try to change `dataType: 'json',` to `dataType: 'jsonp',` or `dataType: 'script',`

Comment: making it 'script called success but the passed in (e) is undefined.

Comment: Is the ajax implementation on a different port or URL?

Comment: not sure I follow but the server does see the ajax request.

Comment: True, but the reason I'm asking to know if you have cross-domain issue!!!

Comment: Well the server and the client are the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript code is located on different port; maybe port 80 and your json request is located on port 62578. Ajax request are allowed only in the same domain, protocol and port.

In order for you to solve your issue, you need to use JSONP datatype or any other similar mechanism (server side solutions).

Checkout [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for more information about JSONP.

Checkout this [example](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/) on how to use JSONP with jQuery ajax call.

Checkout [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AJAX%20call%20cross-domain) for similar questions.

Comment: ah ok Aboodred1, I follow you.